# How to display the user's comment status on the front end

Tags: comments, front-end

How can I display the current status of a user's comment/s (on the front end), that is, "approved" or "pending"

Comment: That is quite standard in every theme. Can you show the code you are using to dislay the comments in your theme?

Comment: I'm using the default GeneratePress theme. Are there any template tags that show the status? I've never seen any themes display a user's comment status on the front end next to their comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying comment status is quite standard in every theme; maybe you have not been notice it but you have seen it for sure. All default themes do it and the default `wp_list_comments()` function does it also and it is the most common function used to display posts comments.

So, if you use default `wp_list_comments()`, you are displaying comment status already; if you are using a custom callback, you can check the comment status, for example like this:

```
<?php
if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) {
   ?>

   <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></p>

   <?php
}
```

Or more accurately, you can use [`wp_get_comment_status()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_comment_status) function:

```
// Return 'deleted', 'approved', 'unapproved', 'spam' or false on failure
$status = wp_get_comment_status( $comment_id );
```

Comment: I don't think it is standard for logged in users who have already had a previous comment approved.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep saying it is not standard instead of looking to the code and reading the explanation I wrote. In fact, the code snippet I posted is from `wp_list_comments()` core function; so it is not only satandard but also the default behaviour of WordPress. A different thing is that you may be using a third party theme that is not doing it. Anyway, standar or not, you know now how to display the comment status.

Comment: I've edited the question and added more methods to display comment status.

Comment: So sorry, I forgot I was using a text replace plugin that hid the standard message... Whoops

Comment: I'm glad you have find the origin of your problem. ;)